# Understand lodash differenceBy iteratee: Different array values greater than x

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I want to write my own iteratee for lodash differenceBy that give me different array values greater than 5.

According documentation. The iteratee is used for "generate the criterion by which they're compared."

Example according documentation:

```
_.differenceBy([1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 8, 10], Math.floor); // [5, 6]
```

This will be similar using Math.floor()

```
let iter_floor = (value) => {
    return Math.floor(value);
};

let differenceBy = _.differenceBy([1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 8, 10], iter_floor);
console.log(differenceBy); // [5, 6]
```

But when I try this

```
let iter_greater = (value) => {
    return value > 5;
};

let differenceBy = _.differenceBy([1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 8, 10], iter_greater);
console.log(differenceBy); // []
```

I get an empty array. I would expect to obtain different array values greater than 5

The source code of lodash differenceBy is here: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.5/lodash.js#L6971

Could you give me an example how to write a iteratee for this case.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm still slightly unclear on what your desired result is. Can you list it explicitly? I'm guessing you wanted just `[6]`?

Comment: Yes, In the example the result should be [6]

Answer (score 4):

By using a function with a comparison, you create  two arrays with boolean values.

This

```
_.differenceBy([1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 8, 10], iter_greater);
```

works in two steps:

1. Map all values and take the iteratee function `iter_greater`

   > ```
   > [1,  2,  3,  5,  6]  ->  [false, false, false, false,  true]
   > [1,  2,  3,  8, 10]  ->  [false, false, false,  true,  true]
   > ```
2. Filter the mapped first array by checking if the value exists in the second array.

   > ```
   > [false, false, false, false,  true]  first array
   > [false, false, false,  true,  true]  second array
   >  false                               exists in 2nd array
   >         false                        exists in 2nd array
   >                false                 exists in 2nd array
   >                       false          exists in 2nd array
   >                               true   exists in 2nd array
   >
   > [                                 ] // no values, 2nd array contains true and false
   > ```

Comment: Excellent explanation about lodash differenceBy

Answer (score 3):

`differenceBy` will run each value through that function, and then if the return value is unique, will keep it.  Your `iter_greater` returns only true or false, neither of which occur only once, so it (as it should) returns an empty array.

You *could* do it like this, which will work in most instances:

```js
let iter_greater = (value) => {
    return value > 5 ? value : undefined;
};

let differenceBy = _.differenceBy([1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 8, 10], iter_greater);
console.log(differenceBy); // []
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

But you'll have issues with:

```js
let iter_greater = (value) => {
    return value > 5 ? value : undefined;
};

let differenceBy = _.differenceBy([1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [], iter_greater);
console.log(differenceBy); // []
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

What you probably want to do, is just chain together `_.difference` and `.filter`:

```js
let differenceBy = _.difference([1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 8, 10]).filter(x => x > 5);
console.log(differenceBy); // []
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
let iter_floor = (value) => {
 return value > 5 && Math.floor(value);
};

let differenceBy = _.differenceBy([1, 2, 3, 5, 6,7,8,9], [1, 2, 3, 8, 10], iter_floor);
console.log(differenceBy); // [6, 7, 9]
```